# Tooltip is not closing when I click outside the chart area in react-native highcharts

Tags: react-native, highcharts

I am trying to close Tooltip appears on the highchairs. It is closing if I click inside the charts anywhere however, if I try to click outside the chart area Tooltip is not closing. How can I tackle within react-native?

I try using the function but I am not sure that will be the best way to do it

```
<LineChart style={[styles.fullWidth, { height: 300, border: 0 }]}
 yAxisTitle={I18n.t("averageSalePricePerSq")} 
xAxisValue={quarterlySales} orientation="horizontal"
 data={sales}
 config={{ tooltip: { enabled: true, shared: true, pointFormat: 
 <span style="color:{point.series.color}">●</span> {point.series.name}: <b>{point.y} AED/sq ft</b><br />`, }, }} />
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample code to demonstrate the problem you are facing?

Comment: are you using any package for tooltip

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highcharts package

Comment: you can try react native elements tooltip

Comment: Thanks let me try that and get back to you

Comment: Can you tell me how to use react native elements in tooltip for high charts